# Is copy the same as Block_copy()?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Are they the same, `copy` and `Block_copy()`? How? or if not, what are the differences?

I was curious about this for a while so I decided to do some researches.

See what I found it my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found the answer. **`copy` and `Block_copy()` are the same**, but not that exactly.

Here is what I found :

---

Let's take a look at the classes of blocks, there are 3 of them :

1. `__NSGlobalBlock__` - You will get a block of this class if you implement a block without any references to the outside of the block.

   ```
   void(^block)() = ^{ NSLog(@"GRAZZZZ"); };
   ```
2. `__NSStackBlock__` - You will get a block of this class if you implement a block with one or more references to the outside of the block, (you will get this when you are running on *non-ARC* environment only. In ARC env, ARC copies it for you automatically).

   ```
   // NON-ARC CODE
   int theOutsider = 1234;
   void(^block)() = ^{ NSLog(@"%d", theOutsider); };
   ```
3. `__NSMallocBlock__` - You will get a block of this class if you copy a `__NSStackBlock__` block.

   ```
   int theOutsider = 1234;
   void(^block1)() = [^{ NSLog(@"%d", theOutsider); } copy]; // NON-ARC VERSION
   void(^block2)() = ^{ NSLog(@"%d", theOutsider); }; // ARC VERSION
   ```

For `__NSGlobalBlock__`, when you call `copy` to it, it does nothing, just return. So, just ignore it. There is no need to move anything to heap. Below is the assembly of `-[__NSGlobalBlock copy]` (its super class) :

```
CoreFoundation`-[__NSGlobalBlock copy]:
   0x7fff8bd016f0:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff8bd016f1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff8bd016f4:  movq   %rdi, %rax
   0x7fff8bd016f7:  popq   %rbp
   0x7fff8bd016f8:  ret    
   0x7fff8bd016f9:  nopl   (%rax)
```

For `__NSStackBlock__` and `__NSMallocBlock__`, when you call `copy` to them, they forward to `copy` method of its super class, `-[NSBlock copy]`. Here is its assembly code on OS X 10.9 SDK :

```
CoreFoundation`-[NSBlock copy]:
   0x7fff8bcc86a0:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff8bcc86a1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff8bcc86a4:  pushq  %rbx
   0x7fff8bcc86a5:  pushq  %rax
   0x7fff8bcc86a6:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
   0x7fff8bcc86a9:  callq  0x7fff8be360ac            ; symbol stub for: objc_collectingEnabled
   0x7fff8bcc86ae:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
   0x7fff8bcc86b1:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
   0x7fff8bcc86b5:  testb  %al, %al
   0x7fff8bcc86b7:  je     0x7fff8bcc86c0            ; -[NSBlock copy] + 32
   0x7fff8bcc86b9:  popq   %rbx
   0x7fff8bcc86ba:  popq   %rbp
   0x7fff8bcc86bb:  jmpq   0x7fff8be361f6            ; symbol stub for: _Block_copy_collectable
   0x7fff8bcc86c0:  popq   %rbx
   0x7fff8bcc86c1:  popq   %rbp
   0x7fff8bcc86c2:  jmpq   0x7fff8be361f0            ; symbol stub for: _Block_copy
   0x7fff8bcc86c7:  nopw   (%rax,%rax)
```

The assembly code on iOS 7.1 SDK :

```
CoreFoundation`-[NSBlock copy]:
   0x17949d0:  pushl  %ebp
   0x17949d1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
   0x17949d3:  popl   %ebp
   0x17949d4:  jmp    0x18d3d8a                 ; symbol stub for: _Block_copy
   0x17949d9:  nopl   (%eax)
```

As you can see in the code, `-[NSBlock copy]` does call `_Block_copy`!.

Enough for `copy`, let's take a look at `Block_copy()`. It is defined in `Block.h` as this :

```
#define Block_copy(...) ((__typeof(__VA_ARGS__))_Block_copy((const void *)(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

`Block_copy()` does call `_Block_copy` too!!

---

To this point, I can summarise that **`copy` and `Block_copy()` are the same!**.

Hope this can help someone with the same curiosity as me :D.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wasn't true when blocks were first introduced, but that's a good study of how it works now.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. BTW, I tested this on OS X 10.9 and iOS 7.1 but the result might change if I ran these on the older SDKs

Comment: Nice research. I had a question recently where this was actually applicable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093802/objective-c-block-lifetime-arc

Comment: "but not that exactly" they *are* exactly the same when used on a block

Comment: @newacct According to the assembly code of `copy`, it does something more than only call to `_Block_copy`. So, I think it is not that exactly.

Comment: @3329: So then, how is it not the same? Show something where they have different semantics.

Comment: It may call `objc_collectingEnabled` or `_Block_copy_collectable` before calling `_Block_copy`. And also there is a very little overhead from `copy` to `_Block_copy`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

When used on an expression of block pointer type, the method `copy` and the function `Block_copy()` are the same. And likewise the method `release` and the function `Block_release()` are the same. The methods `copy` and `release` are just more Objective-C messaging style, since blocks are objects in Objective-C, and are memory managed using `retain` and `release` like other Cocoa objects. On the other hand, when used in C/C++, blocks can only be managed with `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()`.

Comment: Interesting points about using block with C/C++ and `release`. Thank to add more info here! :D